# How can I pass a complex object to another Razor Page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I would like to pass a complex object (a report) from my Index page to an Edit page. I have custom logic to determine which reports a user has access to that would not be captured with Azure Active Directory/roles. Because of this, I cannot simply pass the id as a route parameter and retrieve it on the Edit page.

Currently I have a list of reports on Index.cs that are displayed in the view with an edit button.

```
public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; }
```

When clicking edit I would like to send that report directly to the Edit page.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAsync(long id)
{    
    var report = Reports.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
    return RedirectToPage("./Edit", report);
}
```

However, `RedirectToPage` only takes route data. Is there a different method I should be using here to pass this? If the only way to do so is not best practice then feel free to say so as I would not want to implement this if the pattern is bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `TempData`,here is a demo:

Page1.cshtml:

```
<form method="post">
    <input name="id" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" asp-page-handler="Edit"/>
</form>
```

Page1.cshtml.cs(I use fake data to test):

```
public IEnumerable<Report> Reports { get; set; } 
        public void OnGet()
        {
            
        }
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostEditAsync(long id)
        {
            Reports = new List<Report> { new Report { Id = 1, Name = "Report1" }, new Report { Id = 2, Name = "Report2" }, new Report { Id = 3, Name = "Report3" } };
            var report = Reports.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == id);
            TempData["report"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(report);
            return RedirectToPage("./Edit");
        }
```

Report(I use a simple model to test):

```
public class Report
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

Edit.cshtml.cs:

```
public void OnGet()
        {
            Report r =JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Report>(TempData["report"].ToString());
        }
```

result:
[image]